# Вопрос по библиотеки datejs.com

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

У меня вопрос про библиотеки [datejs.com](http://datejs.com). У меня не получается сделать на ней вот что:

1. При нажатии на кнопку "текущая
       неделя" - надо выставить в инпут
       дату окончания текущей недели (конец
       недели - это всегда воскресенье)
2. При нажатии на кнопку "следующая
       неделя" - точно так же только с
       Понедельника и до воскресенья

Comment: Доки: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Comment: неужели никто не знает ?

Answer (score 1):

1) next sunday
2) next sunday + 8